# spark titlewindow - gettin back data to the main application

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have created a spark titlewindow (using mxml component) which there I select some stuff and want it to get back to the Main application variables.
For example, in the main application I have a var name currMaxPlayers:int and in the TitleWindows I have created a form which you can choose number of players, when selecting the number and then pressing submit button, I want the number that was selected to get back into the currMaxPlayers var in the MainApplication.
I have followed the instructions here http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS6c678f7b363d5da52e8f1ca1124a0430dcf-8000.html  with no success.

Thanks

Comment: Where is the TitleWindow in the display hierarchy w/ respect to the main application?  Are you opening the titleWindow with the PopUpManager?  Or some other way?

Comment: I was able to make it work with events :) thanks flextras and yes, I'm opening it using popupmanager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are opening your custom TitleWindow with the PopUpManager, the PopUpManager should dispatch a custom event with the number of players value and the component which opens the TitleWindow can listen for that event.  Without writing formal tested, code something like this:

```
// In The component that creates the TitleWindow:
var newTitleWindow : MyTitleWindow = new MyTitleWindow();
newTitleWindow.addEventListener('numberOfPlayersChanged', onNumberofPlayersChanged); 
PopUpManager.addPopUp(newTitleWindow , this );
```

Your custom event class:

```
package events
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class MyEvent extends Event
    {
        public var numberOfPlayers:int;

        public function MyEvent (type:String, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false)
        {
            super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
        }
    }
}
```

In the Title Window, dispatch that event:

```
var newEvent : MyEvent = new MyEvent('numberOfPlayersChanged')
newEvent.numberOfPlayers = // whatever procedure you use to get the number of players
dispatchEvent(newEvent);
```

And back to the template which creates the title window:

```
protected function onNumberofPlayersChanged(event:MyEvent):void{
  trace(event.numberOfPlayers);
  // do something else with number of players
}
```